# How to write LaTeX comments in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: installing, latex-misc

I want to write comments in Visual Studio (2012) that contain LaTeX syntax.

There is some plug-in to add to Visual Studio that will enable me to write comment in LaTeX and then see it as LaTeX (e.g. pop up window when I'm pressing some key shortcut or moving over the comment with the mouse)?

I found that someone asked it before at:

[Latex plugin for visual studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195982/latex-plugin-for-visual-studio-2010)

But this didn't help me.

I also found this:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e216ec81-730b-4022-8305-25c39eb1f820

But this didn't help me either (I got a message of "This extension is not installable on any currently installed products") (I installed jmath before).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Well the comments in the first link is not true unfortunately. It is not that on-topic here since the question is more about VS2012 than TeX. The extension you have linked requires JsMath to make the extension work. Did you also try that first?